# The Mocha test is ok despite the URL handler not being implemented

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, google-cloud-functions

I created firebase function and I want to test it locally using [Google Cloud Function Emulator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator) and Mocha.

So I created a test in Mocha to test the REST API update record function using PUT method.

The test goes like this

```
it("should succesfully update data",()=>{
    chai.request(api)
        .put(`/clients/${someId}`)
        .set('Authorization', sometoken)
        .send(somenewdata)
        .end((error,response)=>{
            expect(response.status, "should be 200").to.equal(200);
})
```

When I run the test. it's actually ok.

The problem is I have not implemented the handler for PUT method request to the "clients/:id" URL. So obviously the result should be timeout. I try to run the emulator as well, and send the PUT request using POSTMAN and I got expected result which is timeout.

Other details:

"@types/mocha": "^5.2.5"

Has anyone got any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `chai.request` is async function so must tell Mocha when the test is finished. The workaround is we can use `done`.

```
it("should succesfully update data",(done) => { // specify done
    chai.request(api)
        .put(`/clients/${someId}`)
        .set('Authorization', sometoken)
        .send(somenewdata)
        .end((error,response)=>{
           expect(response.status, "should be 200").to.equal(200);
           done(); // add done
        })
})
```

Ref: 
https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code